# Replace single backslash escape with double backslash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, bing-api, bing-search

I'm using json result from the Bing Search API. In the result, the double quotes is escaped by a single backslash. Javascript however, doesn't accept this. It requires me to escape the double quotes using double backslash. 
So, my question is that how do I replace the single backslash with the double backslash.
For example, a part of the json code is like this

```
"Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday..."
```

I would like it be like this

```
"Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \\"warts and all\\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday..."
```

I tried the following solution

```
json = '"Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday..."';
dfe = JSON.stringify(json);
dfe = dfe.replace(/\\"/g,'\\\\"');
```

However, it didn't work. It replaced all the backslashes before all double quotes. It went from this...

```
\"Description\":\"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday...\"
```

...to this

```
\\"Description\\":\\"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \\"warts and all\\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday...\\"
```

Can anybody tell me how to replace \" with \\" ?

Edit: What I want to do is this

```
<p id="demo"></p>
var json = '{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=1&$top=1","type":"NewsResult"},"ID":"f1c27ae7-bf16-4741-a789-897f4878c2e1","Title":"Britain should stay in EU \u0027warts and all\u0027 - Corbyn | Reuters","Url":"http://www.firstpost.com/world/britain-should-stay-in-eu-warts-and-all-corbyn-reuters-2728514.html","Source":"Firstpost","Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday, making his first big intervention in the referendum campaign as he seeks to counter criticism he is not doing enough to persuade his voters to back the ...","Date":"2016-04-14T05:10:45Z"}],"__next":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=10&$top=10"}}';

obj = JSON.parse(json);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.d.results[0].Title;
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Why not just surround your `json` string with `{}` to make it valid JSON, then parse as-is using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: The actual code has { } surrounding the json code. The json = '...' is the part I have a problem in. @amphetamachine

Comment: Should I post the entire json string? @amphetamachine

Comment: In any case, if I use JSON.parse(), it does not work

Comment: So, Bing gave you back invalid JSON? Interesting...

Comment: No, the json it returned is valid according to the online validators like http://jsonlint.com/.
However, it did not work. I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614483/parsing-json-works-only-partially
There, people suggested me to replace the single backslash escape with double backslash escape.
Exactly how to do that, I could not get through google and other questions here. So, I decided to ask. @amphetamachine

Comment: Can you post full json?

Comment: I have in edited question.
json = ' <HERE>   ';
@SD.

Comment: Why you are assigning JSON as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var json = '{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=1&$top=1","type":"NewsResult"},"ID":"f1c27ae7-bf16-4741-a789-897f4878c2e1","Title":"Britain should stay in EU \u0027warts and all\u0027 - Corbyn | Reuters","Url":"http://www.firstpost.com/world/britain-should-stay-in-eu-warts-and-all-corbyn-reuters-2728514.html","Source":"Firstpost","Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday, making his first big intervention in the referendum campaign as he seeks to counter criticism he is not doing enough to persuade his voters to back the ...","Date":"2016-04-14T05:10:45Z"}],"__next":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=10&$top=10"}}';

obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Try this:

```
var json = {"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=1&$top=1","type":"NewsResult"},"ID":"f1c27ae7-bf16-4741-a789-897f4878c2e1","Title":"Britain should stay in EU \u0027warts and all\u0027 - Corbyn | Reuters","Url":"http://www.firstpost.com/world/britain-should-stay-in-eu-warts-and-all-corbyn-reuters-2728514.html","Source":"Firstpost","Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday, making his first big intervention in the referendum campaign as he seeks to counter criticism he is not doing enough to persuade his voters to back the ...","Date":"2016-04-14T05:10:45Z"}],"__next":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=10&$top=10"}};
```

It will be JSON  object.

Comment: Then what ?
If I do this, and then try to  display   obj.d.results[0].Title, it doesn't work

Comment: Then your `json` variable will be object itself. Try to use `json.d.results[0]`

Comment: API returns data in `JSON` object format using `applicaiton/json` header. So your response is object and not string.

Comment: Welcome, I glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
JSON.stringify({"Description":"LONDON Britain should stay in the EU \"warts and all\", the opposition Labour leader will say on Thursday..."}).replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")
```

Comment: I did this:

    dfe = JSON.stringify(json).replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
    obj = JSON.parse(dfe);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.d.results[0].Title;

It didn't work. @Raul Fernandez